# Aggregate do not return records in order as they are inserted

Tags: mongodb

I am facing one issue with aggregate query.

When I am trying to retrieve records using aggregate ($match), I am not receiving records in same order they are inserted.

but when I am trying to query using find, then I am getting data in same order data inserted.

Comment: Please add Query ? Sample data?  and link if possible https://mongoplayground.net/

Answer (score 0):

In Mongo, the default [internal sort order](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/#return-in-natural-order) is an "unknown" implementation detail.

If a certain order was required then you should use the `$sort` stage otherwise it's considered overhead operation for the storage engine

Without any query criteria, results will be returned by the storage engine in their "natural order" or in layman term the order which they were found, however we don't really know what that order is and we shouldn't rely on it.

So obviously the simple option would be to add a `$sort` stage on `_id` for example, if for some reason you don't have a field you can sort on you can use [$natural](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/meta/natural/) that will return results in the order you expect.